# Postman App on windows: Unable to see application menu and update tab on settings dialog

Tags: postman

I am using the free postman app on win 7.
I am unable to see application menu and update tab on settings dialog.
I have enabled debugging for packed apps as shown below.

> Debugging for packed apps Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS Enables
>   debugging context menu options such as Inspect Element for packed
>   applications. #debug-packed-apps Disable

Is there any way to get these items?

[image: no update tab]

[image: where is the application menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there is a native app and there is a chrome app i.e. Postman for windows and Postman for Chrome.
The Postman for Windows app has the options Certificates and Update but i didn't see the same on Chrome App.

[image]

Also, the interceptor is an add-on on the chrome app whereas the windows native app provides a proxy settings option.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]I am also using Postman Windows app on Win7.
I am getting all those options.

What version are using, the current is v4.10.3.

You may try to uninstall the existing one and re-install the current version.

Comment: @Pandit81 - how can I check the client version - i don't see an about option here

Comment: I have added the picture in my original answer

Comment: Thanks @Pandit81 - The only way i know is to install latest from Chrome web store  - is there a possibility of downloading specific versions